# How to login and execute commands in database using unix?

Tags: linux, perl, unit-testing, shell, unix

I am trying to write one script to execute below step in single script.

Example:

```
bash-3.00$ isql -Ufw -Pframesa -Dcsmain -w2000    
1> select * from UserLogin where UserName ='EPRTUBD'    
2> go    
 UserName             Password                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ExpiryDate                 ProfileID   CCRefillSum              LastCCRefillDate           RBRefillSum              LastRBRefillDate           DBRefillSum              LastDBRefillDate           LockStatus FailedLoginCount
 -------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------- ----------- ------------------------ -------------------------- ------------------------ -------------------------- ------------------------ -------------------------- ---------- ----------------
 EPRTUBD              $1$HN1DOjM6$R9.niqQzUQ/2H4663nRoQ/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     Jun 25 2012  8:04AM         147                     NULL                       NULL                     NULL                       NULL                     NULL                       NULL N                         0

(1 row affected)
1> exit

bash-3.00$
```

Username may be n number. i am trying to give one input file which contain all the username.  can any one guide me? how to assign the username inside this command and execute after login to database.?

Comment: http://dbi.perl.org/ http://p3rl.org/DBI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a way to test this, but the common solution is to use shell "here-docs" to attach the std-in to call to isql. Something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

isql -Ufw -Pframesa -Dcsmain -w2000 <<-EOS   
    select * from UserLogin where UserName ='EPRTUBD'    
    go
EOS
```

Note the '-' in the `<<-EOS`. This is a feature that allows you to indent the here-doc, and allow the closing EOS to be indented too. The EOS **must** be indented with tab chars. If you can't work with tab chars, remove the '-' AND make sure  you EOS are the first chars on a separate line (no trailing white space! ;-)

Also, EOS can be any text, I use EOS for End of Script.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Shellter, Thanks for your response now it works. I used EOB(end of block) instead of EOS. Once again thanks alot